# Возможно ли использвание scipy.optimize.minimize() как функции от двух переменных, но не кортежем/массивом?

Tags: python, scipy

Возможно ли как-то использовать scipy.optimize.minimize() для функции двух и более аргументов, кроме случая передачи параметров кортежем/списком в качестве одной переменной с непосредственной распаковкой на необходимые аргументы внутри функции?

Comment: По-моему невозможно. Но главный вопрос здесь: «А зачем?» Вы всегда можете сделать функцию-обёртку, которая принимает кортеж и оптимизировать её.

Comment: А при чём тут машинное обучение?